# How one can show the equivalence relation from the two systems are equivalent? [In Complex Manifold]

Tags: complex-geometry

This is related with the textbook, "Complex Manifold" by James Morrow and Kunihiko Kodaira.

> From their defintion 2.3,
>
> Two systems $\{ z_i\}_{i\in I}$, $\{ w_j \}_{ j \in J}$ are        equivalent if the maps $z_i (p) \rightarrow w_j (p)$ are  biholomorphic.

Here what i want to show that they really satisfy equivalence relation.

From the definition of biholomorphic, $i.e$

\begin{align}
f_{ji} : z_i (p) \rightarrow w_j(p) \Rightarrow  w_j  \circ z_i^{-1} = f_{ji}
\end{align}
the map $f_{ji}$ and its inverse are holomorphic maps.

---

What i know about bi-holomorphic is 
\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0 \\
& \frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial \bar{z}}=0
\end{align}
And equivalence relations are 
\begin{align}
&a \sim a \\
&a \sim b, \quad \textrm{then} \quad b \sim a \\
& a \sim b,   \quad b \sim c, \quad \textrm{then} \quad a \sim c
\end{align}

how one can come up with equivalence relation from the concept of holomorphic?

---

From user4422, i made my own solution. Please correct wrong points.

I see the $\sim$ as a map thus 
\begin{align}
&a \sim a \\
& f: z_i(p) \rightarrow z_j(p) = z_j \circ z_i^{-1} = I_{ij}
\end{align}
and since identity map is bi-holomoprhic.  reflexcivity holds.

Next 
\begin{align}
f_{ij} : z_i(p) \rightarrow w_j(p) = w_j \circ z_i^{-1}
\end{align}
From the definition of bi-holomorphic 
\begin{align}
f^{-1}_{ij} : w_j(p) \rightarrow z_i(p) =  z_i  \circ w_j^{-1} 
\end{align}
also holds. 
Thus 
\begin{align}
a \sim b \quad \textrm{then} \quad b\sim a
\end{align}

And third one, transivity comes from
\begin{align}
f : z \rightarrow w, \quad g: w \rightarrow q
\end{align}
And thier composition is the map 
\begin{align}
f \circ g : z \rightarrow q
\end{align}
which is bi-holomorphic (Using the fact of composition of holomorphic maps are holomorphic). Thus transivity holds.

Comment: Of course it's an equivalence relation. Reflexivity and Symmetry are obvious. Transitivity is because if $f$ and $g$ is biholomorphic, then $f \circ g$ is also biholomorphic.

Comment: @USER4422, i don't see the obvious thing. Can you give me some hint?

Comment: @user4422, i understand your answer about transitivity. But how can i interprete symmetry and Reflexivity?. $i.e$, for reflexivity, if f is biholomrphic, f~f ? If so, what f~f means?